# Error (404) not foun Angular and php

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, file-not-found

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ProductoServiceService {

  constructor(private http:Http) {}
  //Generamos las funciones que nos serviran para manipular nuestras entidades
  listar() {
    return
```

this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/www/appArtemaya/src/app/productos.php');

```
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your PHP file need to be executed in a PHP environment, you have to run your PHP application separatly from the Angular App.

First, configure a PHP environment to run the PHP Application. Most of time, default configuration use port 80 (with a reverse proxy).

Then, edit your script like following

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ProductoServiceService {

  constructor(private http:Http) {}
  //Generamos las funciones que nos serviran para manipular nuestras entidades
  listar() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost/productos');

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular is running in an instance of Node js, and php is runing in diferent web server (Apache) you must to run your apache service.

then use the correct api link in your http request in angular.